# How to swallow a exception at AfterThrowing in AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

In AspectJ, I want to swallow a exception.

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

 @Pointcut("execution(public * *Throwable(..))")
 void throwableMethod() {}

 @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "throwableMethod()", throwing = "e")
 public void swallowThrowable(Throwable e) throws Exception {
  logger.debug(e.toString());
 }
}

public class TestClass {

 public void testThrowable() {
  throw new Exception();
 }
}
```

Above, it didn't swallow exception. The testThrowable()'s caller still received the exception. I want caller not to receive exception. How can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think it can't be done in `AfterThrowing`. You need to use `Around`.

Answer (score 5):

My solution!

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *Throwable(..))")
    void throwableMethod() {}

    @Around("throwableMethod()")
    public void swallowThrowing(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        try {
            pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.debug("swallow " + e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks again.