# Using @Transactional in a standalone app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am developing a standalone application which exposes a REST API.

I made it with the most standards libraries I could find. Basically, I use JPA2, Hibernate (and Guice for dependency injection). Here is what my main dependencies look like :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager` are injected via a custom Guice `Provider`.

Everything works fine except that up to now, I have to handle transactions manually like :

```
@javax.inject.Inject
private EntityManager em;

public void foo() {
  try {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    doSomething();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
  } catch() {
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
  }
}
```

and I don't want to use a try/catch everytime I need a transaction. In another project, with Spring in a servlet container, I could simply write it like this :

```
@Transactional
public void foo() {
  doSomething();
}
```

Is there a non-spring solution? (I already use Guice for dependency injection).

**EDIT** (answer to Adam Siemion). Here is how I can create 1 EntityManager/Thread by customizing my Guice's EntityManager Provider. It still seems dangerous to me because the very same EntityManager (maybe in a dirty state) can be use on the next Transaction :

```
public class EntityManagerProvider implements Provider<EntityManager> {

  private static ThreadLocal<EntityManager> entityManagerThreadLocal
    = new ThreadLocal<>();

  @Inject
  private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  @Override
  public EntityManager get() {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerThreadLocal.get();
    if(entityManager == null) {
      entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
      entityManagerThreadLocal.set(entityManager);
    }
    return entityManager;
  }

}
```

Comment: non-spring solution is java EE

Comment: @RomanC I don't get what you mean. AFAIK, Java EE != servlet container. In Java EE, I saw that `javax.transaction.Transactional` already exists but it seems that I lack a bit of configuration (or an implementation) to have it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a custom interceptor

```
TransactionalMethodInterceptor interceptor = new TransactionalMethodInterceptor();
```

in Guice:

```
bindInterceptor(annotatedWith(Transactional.class), any(), interceptor);
bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(Transactional.class), interceptor);
```

but first inject `EntityManager` to your `TransactionalMethodInterceptor`:

```
requestInjection(interceptor);
```

which will intercept all the calls to the methods annotated with the `Transactional` annotation.

And your interceptor might be something along these lines:

```
class TransactionalMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  @javax.inject.Inject
  private EntityManager em;

  @Override
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    try {
      Object result = invocation.proceed();
      em.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      em.rollback();
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

}

`MethodInterceptor` and `MethodInvocation` come from the [aopalliance](http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net) library.

Comment: This is clear. It is impressive that so few lines of code are so powerful :) Nevertheless, I can have it working only if I get the same instance of EntityManager in the DAO class and in the interceptor which is easy to understand. Up to now, the only way I found is to inject the `EntityManager` as a `Singleton` which seems like anti²-pattern. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I know two options: `DataSourceTransactionManager` from Spring or write your implementation. If you choose the second option please share the code here so I can switch from the first option! :)

Comment: Oh, you use JPA, so you do not work with `DataSource`, but with `EntityManager`, so I guess `DataSourceTransactionManager` is not an option.

Comment: `Singleton` made me think about multi-threading problems. Multi-threading problems made me think about `ThreadLocal` (basically, I store the `EntityManager` in the `Thread`) which ensures that the `EntityManager` is not shared among several threads. I tested and it works but I wonder wether it is still an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you could use AspectJ for such purposes. Kidnly check this example

[How to swallow a exception at AfterThrowing in AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396167/how-to-swallow-a-exception-at-afterthrowing-in-aspectj)

In this case you should declare try-catch block only once in your aspect